# Dictionary on derived classes

Tags: c#, dictionary, derived-class

I have two classes like this:

```
class Base : IEquatable<Base>
{
    int A;

    public Base(int a)
    {
       A = a;
    }
    public bool Equals([AllowNull] Base other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;
        else
            return (A == other.A);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as Base);
    }
    public static bool operator==(Base one, Base two)
    {
        return (one is null) ? (two is null) : one.Equals(two);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Base one, Base two)
    {
        return !(one == two);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(A);
    }
}
class Derived : Base, IEquatable<Derived>
{
    int B;

    public Derived(int a, int b)
       : base(a)
    {
       B = b;
    }
    public bool Equals([AllowNull] Derived other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;
        else
            return (A == other.A) && (B == other.B);
    }
    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return Equals(other as Derived);
    }
    public static bool operator==(Derived one, Derived two)
    {
        return (one is null) ? (two is null) : one.Equals(two);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(Derived one, Derived two)
    {
        return !(one == two);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(A, B);
    }
}
```

So now if I have a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<Base, string> Dict = new Dictionary<Base, string>();
```

I want to make sure that the dictionary correctly separates all the different values:

```
Dict[new Base(1)] = "one";
Dict[new Derived(1, 2)] = "one, two";
Dict[new Derived(1, 3)] = "one, three";

Assert.AreEqual(3, Dict.Count);

Derived der13again = new Derived(1, 3);

Assert.IsTrue(Dict.ContainsKey(der13again));
// Notice this Assert is why I had to override IEquatable<> so that the
// keys are compared by value, not by reference
```

I need to make sure it works in all situations, **even the rare cases where there's a hash collision**.  In order to force a hash collision, I edited Derived.GetHashCode() to just return HashCode.Combine(A).  When I do this, and add some debugging, the first Assert fails (the dictionary only contains 1 entry) and I get this output:

```
// Adding [Base 1] to dict
Base.GetHashCode() returning -1259686161 [this=[Base 1]]
dict has 1 members
// So far so good

// Step 2: Adding [Derived 1, 2] to dict
Derived.GetHashCode() returning -1259686161 [this=[Derived 1, 2]]
// Dictionary notices the hash collision and wonders if it's actually
// the same key value, so it calls Equals() to check if old key == new key
// BUT USES BASE.EQUALS
Base.Equals(Base other=[Derived 1, 2])
// Dictionary decides the two keys are identical, so updates the value:
dict has 1 members
dict[b]=one, two
dict[d1]=one, two

// Adding [Derived 1, 3] to dict
Derived.GetHashCode() returning -1259686161 [this=[Derived 1, 3]]
// Again, hash collision, Dictionary wonders if it's the same key
Base.Equals(Base other=[Derived 1, 3])
// Decides it's the same key so just updates the value
dict has 1 members
dict[b]=one, three
dict[d1]=one, three
dict[d2]=one, three
```

Edit: Per Jon Skeet's comment, I updated Base.Equals() functions like so:

```
public bool Equals([AllowNull] Base other)
{
    if (other is null)
        return false;
    else if (GetType() != other.GetType())
        return false;
    else
        return (A == other.A);
}
```

and that helps in that now I have two objects in my dictionary, but still not 3 (Dictionary still uses Base.Equals to compare the two Derived values, and thus finds they are equal)

How can I get Dictionary to correctly handle derived classes?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to _achieve_ with that dictionary?

Comment: This is a made-up example showing the relevant pieces of the problem.  The actual problem is (1) too long to include in a stackoverflow post, and (2) proprietary.

Comment: It would be a good idea for you to read about how collisions are handled in hashtables. It's not what you assume.

Comment: You are quite right, I've tweaked my original post to not imply that Equals is part of a normal hash collision process.

Comment: I believe your `Equals` implementations are basically broken - because the [requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-5.0) that "`x.Equals(y)` returns the same value as `y.Equals(x)`" is violated. `base.Equals(der1)` will return true, whereas `der1.Equals(base)` will return false. Once you've got a *consistent* equality implementation, everything should be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet you raise a good point, I've added to my original post to talk about this

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, if you do not pass a custom EqualityComparer, will call `EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default`, which will end up beeing a wrapper for `IEquatable<TKey>` or more specific in your case `IEquatable<Base>`.

See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,94

It does not handle any derived types. All it does care about, is that implementation of `IEquatable<Base>`.

What you can do is explicitely reimplement that interface, on your derived types, to alter that behaviour. Or easier, make those Base-methods virtual.

But that would mean, that derived types behave differently than their basetype resulting in a violation of [Liskov subsitution principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) if im not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution, based on CSharpie's ideas, is to have Derived implement IEquatable like so:

```
class Derived : Base, IEquatable<Derived>, IEquatable<Base>
{
    // Add a new function:
    public new bool Equals([AllowNull] Base other)
    {
        if (other is Derived der)
            return Equals(der);
        return false;
    }
// This works if Base.Equals(Base) contains "else if (GetType() != other.GetType()) return false;"
```

Another way to do this is to make Base.Equals(Base) virtual and override it in Derived.

I have verified that either solution works, but they're sub-optimum in two ways:

- Since the point of this exercise is to make Dictionary work correctly, it doesn't taste right to require changes to the Base/Derived hierarchy
- It would be better to have a solution that works "in general", rather than requiring a change to every such class hierarchy
- If the class hierarchy were more complex - if, for example, I had "class Fred : Derived" and "class George : Fred", then George would have to override IEquatable<George>, IEquatable<Fred>, IEquatable<Derived>, and IEquatable<Base> to be certain of success

The other solution that CSharpie mentioned looks something like this:

```
public class BaseComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    static readonly Dictionary<Type, IEqualityComparer> Comparers = new Dictionary<Type, IEqualityComparer>();
    static readonly object ComparersLock = new object();

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] T x, [AllowNull] T y)
    {
        if (x is null)
            return (y is null);
        else if (y is null)
            return false;
        else if (x.GetType() != y.GetType())
            return false;
        else if (x.GetType() == typeof(T))
            return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y);

        IEqualityComparer? comparer = null;
        lock (ComparersLock)
            Comparers.TryGetValue(x.GetType(), out comparer);
        if (comparer == null)
        {
            var tec = typeof(EqualityComparer<>);
            Type specific = tec.MakeGenericType(x.GetType());
            var defProp = specific.GetProperty("Default");
            if (defProp == null)
                throw new Exception("No Default property on " + specific);
            var value = defProp.GetValue(null);
            if (value is IEqualityComparer comp)
            {
                comparer = comp;
                lock (ComparersLock)
                    Comparers[x.GetType()] = comparer;
            }
            else
                throw new Exception("No value for " + defProp);
        }

        return comparer.Equals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] T obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

which is nice in that it doesn't require any additional code to Base or Derived, but does have a little reflection hacking in it.

Comment: I do not understand why you are even Using IEquatable<T> when you force it to use a EqualityComparer instead, that also fallbacks to the DefaultComparer which does object.Equals and object.GetHashcode.

I think you miss the whole point of how IEquatable<T> and IEqualityComparer<T> work.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep changing things around, but as Heretic Monkey pointed out, the original post had gotten long and convoluted.  I've updated my original post to include a brief explanation of why I'm using IEquatable<>

Comment: I just noticed, you used new to create a new equals method. You want to make the method virtual and override it. Do not use new.

Comment: I added a note about making Base.Equals(Base) virtual, that certainly works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the functionality in the regular `Equals` method:

```
class Base : IEquatable<Base>
{
    // ...

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] Base other)
    {
        return Equals((object) other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var that = other as Base;

        return that != null 
            && this.GetType == that.GetType
            && this.A == that.A;
    }
    // ...
}

class Derived : Base, IEquatable<Derived>
{
    // ...

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] Derived other)
    {
        return Equals((object) other)
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        var that = other as Derived;

        return base.Equals(other) 
            && this.B == that.B;
    }
    // ...
}
```